# Getting Index of an item in an arraylist;

Tags: java, arraylist, find, element, indexof

I have a Class called `AuctionItem`. The `AuctionItem` Class has a method called `getName()` that returns a `String`. If I have an `ArrayList` of type `AuctionItem`, what is the best way to return the index of an item in the `ArrayList` that has a specific name?

I know that there is an `.indexOf()` function. The parameter for this function is an object. To find the item that has a name, should I just use a for loop, and when the item is found, return the element position in the `ArrayList`?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18):

I think a for-loop should be a valid solution :

```
    public int getIndexByname(String pName)
    {
        for(AuctionItem _item : *yourArray*)
        {
            if(_item.getName().equals(pName))
                return *yourarray*.indexOf(_item)
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Yes.you have to loop it

```
public int getIndex(String itemName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++)
    {
        AuctionItem auction = arraylist.get(i);
        if (itemName.equals(auction.getname()))
        {
            return i;
        }
    } 

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Life saver... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

Basically you need to look up `ArrayList` element based on name `getName`. Two approaches to this problem:

1- Don't use `ArrayList`, Use `HashMap<String,AutionItem>` where `String` would be name

2- Use `getName` to generate index and use index based addition into array list `list.add(int index, E element)`. One way to generate index from name would be to use its hashCode and modulo by `ArrayList` current size (something similar what is used inside `HashMap`)

Answer (score 4):

.indexOf() works well.
If you want an example here is one:

```
  ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<String>();
  example.add("AB");
  example.add("CD");
  example.add("EF");
  example.add("GH");
  example.add("IJ");
  example.add("KL");
  example.add("MN");

  System.out.println("Index of 'AB': "+example.indexOf("AB"));
  System.out.println("Index of 'KL': "+example.indexOf("KL"));
  System.out.println("Index of 'AA': "+example.indexOf("AA"));
  System.out.println("Index of 'EF': "+example.indexOf("EF"));
```

will give you an output of

```
Index of 'AB': 0
Index of 'KL': 5
Index of 'AA': -1
Index of 'EF': 2
```

Note: This method returns -1 if the specified element is not present in the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   if (list.get(i) .getName().equalsIgnoreCase("myName")) {
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To find the item that has a name, should I just use a for loop, and when the item is found, return the element position in the ArrayList?

Yes to the loop (either using indexes or an `Iterator`). On the return value, either return its index, or the item iteself, depending on your needs. `ArrayList` doesn't have an `indexOf`(Object target, [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) compare)` or similar. Now that Java is getting lambda expressions (in Java 8, ~March 2014), I expect we'll see APIs get methods that accept lambdas for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `hashCode`/`equals` of your `AuctionItem` so that two of them are equal if they have the same name. When you do this you can use the methods `indexOf` and `contains` of the `ArrayList` like this: `arrayList.indexOf(new AuctionItem("The name"))`. Or when you assume in the equals method that a String is passed: `arrayList.indexOf("The name")`. But that's not the best design.

But I would also prefer using a `HashMap` to map the name to the item.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a brute force loop through the list (eg 1 to 10000), rather use an iterative search approach :
The List needs to be sorted by the element to be tested.

Start search at the middle element size()/2  eg 5000
if search item greater than element at 5000, then test the element at the midpoint between the upper(10000) and midpoint(5000) - 7500

keep doing this until you reach the match (or use a brute force loop through once you get down to a smaller range (eg 20 items)

You can search a list of 10000 in around 13 to 14 tests, rather than potentially 9999 tests.