# Using indexOf in ArrayList of Object

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Basically I have this problem of retrieving the index from ArrayList where `Person` is a class

My `Person` class

```
public class Person{
  private String name;
  private String age;

  public Person(String name, String age){
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
  }
}
```

My `Main` class

```
ArrayList<Person> person;

for(int i = 0；i < 3; i++){
  person.add(new Person("John Doe " + i, ""+i));
}
```

My `indexOf` code

```
int index = person.indexOf("2");
```

So I want to retrieve the index where `"2"` is located, but it returned error instead. So clearly I'm not using `indexOf` properly. So any guidance would be appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: "2" is a String, but the ArrayList contains Person objects. How do you expect to compare these?

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, because it's a `List<Person>` not a `List<String>`, if you want the element at index 2, use `#get(index)`, aka `.get(2)`

Comment: do you want to get the element at index 2 or person with age 2 ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you store the age as a String rather than as a number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393709/getting-index-of-an-item-in-an-arraylist

Comment: First of all initialize your object to `ArrayList<Calendar> person = new ArrayList<Calendar>();`

Comment: @Rogue What I want to retrieve is actually the index of where the value `2` located within the instance of the existed `person`. Out of the `person` that was created, I want to get the index of where the person with the age value of `2`. Does that make more sense ? Sorry if I wasn't clear on my question.

Comment: @Saravana the latter one.

Comment: Then you would use a loop and find the element of the list where the property matches, or use streams.